# Get current Timezone offset from offset saved before daylight started

Tags: php, timezone, offset, dst

I have saved utc date with client timezone offset  as -570 of australia/adelaide  which was offset before  DAY LIGHT SAVING STARTED . Now I need to find the current offset  using -570  after daylight saving has started using php code? Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored `-570` (meaning UTC+09:30), and did not store `"Australia/Adelaide"`, then no - there is no way to determine this.  It doesn't matter which programming language you are using.

The reason is simply that while South Australia (represented by `Australia/Adelaide`) switches between UTC+09:30 and UTC+10:30 for daylight saving time, Northern Territory (represented by `Australia/Darwin`) uses UTC+09:30 the entire year.

If you happened to have a timestamp during the summer period that was associated with UTC+09:30, then you could reasonably assert that it was associated with `Australia/Darwin` - but only because it happens to be the only one observing that offset during that time.  The same cannot be said for a timestamp during the winter period, or for the general case worldwide.

In other words, `-570` might refer to either `Australia/Adelaide` or `Australia/Darwin`.

Or it might even refer to Yancowinna county of New South Wales (represented by `Australia/Broken_Hill`), which follows Adelaide instead of the rest of NSW.

See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and [Time in Australia on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia).